# Что неправильно в SQL запросе?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Есть такой SQL запрос:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+DBH.DocK.TABLE_NAME+" where "+DBH.DocK.DC.DOC_ID+"='"+uniqueID+"'"+
                " and where "+DBH.DocK.DC.TAB_ID+"='"+tabID+"'",null);
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

> ```
> Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.                                                                             
>
> (near "where": syntax error (code 1): ,
>  while compiling: select * from dock where file_id='fe485f5e-7b2a-11e6-a21d-984be174a0cc' and where tabID='1')
> ```

Что неправильно? Может, я где-то кавычку пропустила или пробел?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да, у вас ошибка.

Правильный запрос:

```
select *
from dock
where file_id='fe485f5e-7b2a-11e6-a21d-984be174a0cc'
      and tabID='1'
```

А у вас:

```
select *
from dock
where file_id='fe485f5e-7b2a-11e6-a21d-984be174a0cc'
      and **where** tabID='1'
```

Comment: Точно,  спасибо!